# How to measure the accuracy of a Doc2vec model?

Tags: gensim, unsupervised-learning, doc2vec

I have a dataset of reviews for different Hotels. 
I'm trying to find out similar hotels using the reviews of hotels. So, I'm using a `Doc2vec` algorithm to achieve this.

Is there any way to measure the accuracy of a `Doc2Vec` model using `Gensim`, rather than evaluating the results using `most_similar()` function of `Gensim`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `Doc2Vec` (aka the 'Paragraph Vector' algorithm) is an unsupervised method, there are no strictly right or wrong results – just trained models that are better or worse for some downstream task.

How do you, personally, in your own mind, determine if the results are valuable to your project?

You have to capture some of that judgement into a repeatable process – for example, one way might be hand-crafting a list of pairs of hotels that, in your expert human-level judgement, "ought to be more similar" to each other than others, or perhaps in each others' "top N" closest results. Then score the `Doc2Vec` model against that ideal, compared to other methods (or multiple alternatively-parameterized runs of `Doc2Vec`).

You might be able to bootstrap some "ought to be more similar" pairs from existing sources of data. For example, maybe two hotels that are in the same chain "ought to be more similar" to each other than some random third hotel. (So, the outside data of their brand-name would guide your evaluation, ideally if you were sure that the brand name didn't leak into the document texts used to train the model.) Or maybe, two hotels that are both geographically & price-wise near each other "ought to be more similar" than some random third.

But there's no standard/automatic idea of "accuracy" for such fuzzy representations on the domain of all possible documents and project goals. You need to develop your own custom evaluations to be able to choose between algorithms, or tune the algorithms.

Comment: Okay.Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

I used topic modeling(LDA with gensim/mallet) nearest neighbor as a baseline to compare the results of Doc2Vec. Granted this is very crude way, but at least you can see if Doc2Vec results aligns with results of topic model to some degree.

Say you have 10 nearest neighbor from Doc2vec and Topic model for a input query/doc, you can do Jaccard similarity or NDCG between these two sets to see how close they are. This will give confidence in your doc2vec results. Theory is that Doc2Vec results are supposed to be better than topic modeling as topic modeling cannot find semantically similar documents like Doc2vec. So, where the results vary dramatically between the two, you can introduce human judgement.